# How to set dark theme for KDE Apps on Xubuntu?

Tags: kde, theme, xubuntu, dark-mode

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with XFCE4 dark theme, but KDE apps (for example: ktorrent) are using default bright theme.
How to set those apps globally to use dark theme?

(previously I never had this problem at all since I almost never use KDE apps)

Gnome apps (gnome-disks, gprename) themes using dark theme without any manual settings (probably respecting xfce4's settings? or their default are already dark mode)

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, found the answer: [Get Qt5 Apps To Use Native Gtk+ Style In Ubuntu Or Debian](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/05/get-qt5-apps-to-use-native-gtk-style-in.html), I was searching with wrong keyword, it should be "how change qt apps theme in ubuntu"

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins
```

solved the issue (you'll need to restart the KDE apps) and it would use dark theme normally.

Answer (score 2):

To changes the KDE apps theming you would need system settings from KDE `systemsettings5` this will save the theme settings under `~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals`.

Otherwise as KDE is using Qt for its application the parameter `--style` can be used to change the theme per application as follow:

```
konsole --style "Adwaita"
```

Comment: i've installed `systemsettings` package, but after opening `systemsettings5` it only have 4 configuration options: shortcuts, applications, settings (network), and kde connect; no settings for theme https://ibb.co/3dn1Wzw

Comment: I guess some other package are missing to have the theme category